# Passing the value of a button into a text field

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm having some trouble with getting Javascript to pass a value (which is stored in local storage) into a textfield. Ideally, I'd like for someone to be able to click the 'apply here' button on one page, have the job number stored in local storage and then have it auto-populate the job number field on my application page with the job number.

This is what I've got so far, I have a feeling that I haven't assigned things correctly.

html (on submit page)

```
    <p>


<form id="applyjob1" action="enquire.html" method="get">
<input type="submit" id="job1" value="Apply for Job" />
</form>

</p>
```

html (field I'm trying to put data into)

```
 Job Reference Number <input required="required" id="jobNo" name="jobno" type="text" /> </br />
```

Javascript

```
  window.onload = function init() {
    var jobID = document.getElementById("job"); /*button name */

        jobID.onsubmit = passJob; /*executes passJob function */
    }


    function passJob(){
        var jobSubmit = localstorage.jobID("1984"); /*assigns localstorage*/

        if (jobSubmit != undefined){
        document.getElementById("jobNo").value = localstorage.jobID;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code would work for your fuction.

```
    function passJob(){
       localStorage.setItem("jobID", "1984");

       if (localStorage.jobID != undefined) {
           document.getElementById("jobNo").value = localStorage.jobID;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the `jobSubmit` wrongly. To set item, use `localStorage.setItem('key', value)`. Note the casing as it matters. 
So basically you should do

```
var jobSubmit = localStorage.setItem(,"jobID", "1984"); // assigns jobSubmit
```

And I don't see any element with `id="job"`